# Check all with PHP like JQuery Check-all

Tags: php

Does possible to have a check all in PHP? because in jQuery you can have this code to **checkall checkboxes**

```
$(function() {
  $('.chk_boxes').click(function() {
    $('.chk_boxes1').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

does it possible in PHP? if Yes can you give an explanation how to make it?

Comment: PHP runs server-side. It doesn't make sense to try in that context.

Comment: No you can't you can't manipulate check-boxes(Client side) with PHP(Server side) code.

Comment: @AlokPatel thank you for explanation

Comment: @Phylogenesis thank you for answering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does it possible in PHP?

It is **not** possible. PHP doesn't even have read access to those checkboxes until that page is submitted to a PHP file, let alone write access.

PHP Can not manipulate your DOM elements just like JavaScript can. Once the page is loaded you can add/remove or manipulate elements on it using a client side language like JS. PHP is long asleep by then even if PHP served the page.

Comment: Haha - Sorry was having some fun :)

Comment: Don't be sorry, it made me laugh, but now I'm trying to resist the edit button...... *must step back, count to five, deep breath....* `:-D`

Comment: ahh i see thank you sir @HankyPanky im just asking since I cant search it